# reference overlay numbers with names

Tags: beamer, overlays

I have two-column slides where there is a tikz figure on the left, and itemization on the right. There is >10 overlays due to pauses in the itemization, and some pieces of the tikz picture are added/removed/modified accordingly (with `\only<>`) as are the items uncovered.

It is easy to break the code by adding one `\pause`, because all numbers have to be rewritten.

Is there a way (no hint in Beamer Manual, chap. 9) to assign the value of `beamerpause` counter to symbolic names, at the point when that part gets uncovered for the first time, something like (needs multiple passes to be resolved) the following?

```
\begin{column}{..}
   \only</bar->{...}  % <2-> (use e.g. / to reference labels)
   \only<-/baz>{...}  % <-3>
\end{column}
\begin{column{..}
   \begin{itemize}
      \item foo \pause
      \item bar \firstUncoveredLabel{bar}\pause % assign 2 to label /bar
      \item baz \pause[baz]       % nicer syntax; assign 3 to label /baz
      \item end
   \end{itemize}
\end{column}
```

**EDIT:** minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
      \begin{columns}
         \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \tikz{
               \draw< -3>        (0,0) grid (3,3);
               \draw<2-3>[red]   (0,0) -- (3,1);
               \draw<3- >[green] (0,0) -- (3,2);
               \draw<4  >[blue]  (0,0) -- (3,3);
            }
         \end{column}
         \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
               %%%% uncomment this item and all numbers above have to be shifted :-(
               % \item important remark at the beginning \pause 
               \item grid \pause
               \item grid, red \pause
               \item grid, red, green \pause
               \item green, blue
            \end{itemize}
         \end{column}
      \end{columns}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and this is what I dream of (*does not compile*):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
      \begin{columns}
         \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \tikz{
               %% use symbolic names for overlay specificaiton
               \draw<-/gridRedGreen>                (0,0) grid (3,3);
               \draw</gridRed-/gridRedGreen>[red]   (0,0) -- (3,1);
               \draw</gridRedGreen->        [green] (0,0) -- (3,2);
               \draw</last>                 [blue]  (0,0) -- (3,3);
            }
         \end{column}
         \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
               %%%% uncomment and overlays are still correct :-)
               % \item important remark at the beginning \pause 
               \item grid                \pause[grid]
               \item grid, red           \pause[gridRed]
               \item grid, red, green    \pause[gridRedGreen]
               \item green, blue      
            \end{itemize}
         \end{column}
      \end{columns}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's a possible way to reference overlays by name:

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\savepause}[1]{\only<1>{\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\pauseentry{\the\c@framenumber}{#1}{\the\c@beamerpauses}}}}
\newcommand*{\usepause}[1]{\@ifundefined{pauses@\the\c@framenumber @#1}{1}{\@nameuse{pauses@\the\c@framenumber @#1}}}
\newcommand*{\pauseentry}[3]{\global\@namedef{pauses@#1@#2}{#3}}
\makeatother
```

Include this code somewhere into the preamble of your document, i. e. between `\documentclass{beamer}` and `\begin{document}`. It defines two userlevel commands, `\savepause` and `\usepause`:

- `\savepause{overlayname}` saves the current value of the counter `beamerpauses` as `overlayname`. Issue it immediatly before the `\pause` command.
- `\usepause{overlayname}` refers to the previously saved value of `overlayname`, so if you e.g. used `\savepause{overlayname}` on the third overlay, `\usepause{overlayname}` will expand to 3.

As the values will be saved to the auxiliary file, this needs at least two LaTeX runs to produce a stable output.

You can't use the syntax `\pause[overlayname]` to save the value as you suggested because the optional argument is already used by `beamer` itself. However, you can define your own command for convenience:

```
\newcommand*{\mypause}[1]{\savepause{#1}\pause}
```

which would be used like `\mypause{overlayname}`.

#### Example code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\savepause}[1]{\only<1>{\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\pauseentry{\the\c@framenumber}{#1}{\the\c@beamerpauses}}}}
\newcommand*{\pauseentry}[3]{\global\@namedef{pauses@#1@#2}{#3}}
\newcommand*{\usepause}[1]{\@ifundefined{pauses@\the\c@framenumber @#1}{1}{\@nameuse{pauses@\the\c@framenumber @#1}}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
      \begin{columns}
         \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \tikz{
               %% use symbolic names for overlay specificaiton
               \draw<-\usepause{gridRedGreen}>                (0,0) grid (3,3);
               \draw<\usepause{gridRed}-\usepause{gridRedGreen}>[red]   (0,0) -- (3,1);
               \draw<\usepause{gridRedGreen}->        [green] (0,0) -- (3,2);
               \draw<\usepause{last}>                 [blue]  (0,0) -- (3,3);
            }
         \end{column}
         \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
               %%%% uncommented and overlays are still correct :-)
               \item important remark at the beginning \pause 
               \item grid                \savepause{grid}\pause
               \item grid, red           \savepause{gridRed}\pause
               \item grid, red, green    \savepause{gridRedGreen}\pause
               \item green, blue      
            \end{itemize}
         \end{column}
      \end{columns}
  \savepause{last} 
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

#### Output after two LaTeX runs (click on the image to see it full size):

[image: output of the example code (five frames)]

Comment: Very nice and usable. I tried to remove the `\pause`s from your example using `[<+->]` as an argument to the enumeration instead. Now the reference always points a frame too late. As I did not completely understand the effects of many commands in your solution, I failed to decrement he value before saving. Can you think of a way to use `\item<+-> Lorem ipsum \savepause{a}` so that something marked with `\usepause{a}` will show up exactly at the same time the item does?

Comment: @XZS The problem with `[<+->]` is that the counter `beamerpauses` is increased at the beginning of the `\item` and not at the end. Unfortunately I can't think of a way to detect this automatically, but but I can offer you a workaround: Replace the definition of `\savepause` above by `\DeclareRobustCommand*{\savepause}[2][0]{\only<1>{\advance\c@beamerpauses by#1\relax\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\pauseentry{\the\c@framenumber}{#2}{\the\c@beamerpauses}}\advance\c@beamerpauses by-#1\relax}}` and use `\savepause[-1]{a}` in the `itemize` environment, like this will refer to the correct overlay.

Comment: Very handy. Could the optional offset also be applied to the `\usepause` command? Then, one could write `\usepause[2]{grid} as equivalent to `\usepause{gridRedGreen}` to make ranges more intuitive.

Comment: @XZS Sure, you can define `\def\usepauseoffset[#1]#2{\number\numexpr\usepause{#2}+#1\relax}` to be used like `\usepauseoffset[2]{grid}`. The different name is necessary as normal macros with an optional argument unfortunately don't work in overlay specifications due to the way beamer internally processes them.

Comment: I use the second command version of `savepause` ouside the item environment and `usepause` in items then I don't need the `\pause` command. I put `savepause` after the slide command I want to refer. See an example here : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253815/beamer-how-to-avoid-the-lack-of-access-to-labelled-slide-not-frame-numbers