# Is it possible to implement a "label-goto"-like workflow in composing overlay?

Tags: beamer, overlays

I don't want to hardly code the value `6` in the following code as:

- I have to manually count the number of steps.
- The mechanism breaks when a block of code (`\Atom` in this example) is repeated in the same frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}
\PreviewBorder=12pt

\def\Atom{%
    \bgroup
    \only<6->{\psset{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan}}
    \pscustom[linejoin=0]
    {
        \only<+->{\moveto(0,0)}
        \only<+->{\lineto(2,0)}
        \only<+->{\lineto(2,2)}
        \only<+->{\lineto(0,2)}
        \only<+->{\closepath}
    }
    \egroup
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-3)(3,3)
        \Atom
        \psscalebox{-1 -1}{\Atom}
\end{pspicture} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to implement  a "label-goto"-like workflow in composing overlay? Something similar to

```
label xxx:

overlay 1
overlay 2
overlay 3

goto xxx
```

Comment: Actually I can make `\Atom` accepts an argument, e.g., `\Atom{6}` and `\Atom{12}` but it looks cumbersome!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use *named overlays* as introduced in [reference overlay numbers with names](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34458/3323): The general idea is to have a command `\savepause{name}`, which saves the current value of the counter `beamerpauses`. You can then reference this value by using `\usepause{name}` in an overlay specification: `\only<\usepause{name}->{...}`.

In your case, you want the same operation `\Atom` processed multiple times with different settings. The necessary overlay specifications can be determined by creating named overlays `square0`, `square1`, ..., which point to the "end" of the corresponding square drawn by `\Atom`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}
\PreviewBorder=12pt

\def\Atom{%
    \bgroup
    \only<\currentsquareend->{\psset{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan}}
    \pscustom[linejoin=0]
    {
        \only<+->{\moveto(0,0)}
        \only<+->{\lineto(2,0)}
        \only<+->{\lineto(2,2)}
        \only<+->{\lineto(0,2)}
        \only<+->{\closepath}
    }
    \egroup
    \squarecompleted
}

% Reference overlay numbers with names (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50493)
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\savepause}[1]{\only<1>{\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\pauseentry{\the\c@framenumber}{#1}{\the\c@beamerpauses}}}}
\newcommand*{\pauseentry}[3]{\global\@namedef{pauses@#1@#2}{#3}}
\newcommand*{\usepause}[1]{\@ifundefined{pauses@\the\c@framenumber @#1}{1}{\@nameuse{pauses@\the\c@framenumber @#1}}}
\makeatother

\newcounter{squares}
\newcommand*{\squarecompleted}{\savepause{square\thesquares}\stepcounter{squares}}
\newcommand*{\currentsquareend}{\usepause{square\thesquares}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\setcounter{squares}{0}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-3)(3,3)
        \Atom
        \psscalebox{-1 -1}{\Atom}
\end{pspicture} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: animated output result, showing 11 frames]

The document has to be compiled *twice* in order to produce correct results.

#### How it works

A counter `squares` is used to automate the creation of the necessary named overlays. This is done by introducing two new macros: `\squarecompleted` is invoked at the end of `\Atom`, it creates a new named overlay `square\thesquares` (i.e. `square0`, `square1`, ...) and steps the counter `squares`. This named overlay can be retrieved with `\currentsquareend`, which returns the end frame for the current square and is used in

```
\only<\currentsquareend->{\psset{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan}}
```

Note also the `\setcounter{squares}{0}` at the beginning of the `frame`: It is crucial to have it exactly there, and not only in the preamble for example, as each `frame` is processed multiple times in order to create the animation.