# Adjusted reference of overlay numbers with names

Tags: beamer, macros, overlays

I am trying to reference my beamer overlays by an identifier, much like in this question: [reference overlay numbers with names](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34458/reference-overlay-numbers-with-names).

Since I am using `\visible<+->{}` (where the beamerpauses counter is incremented after the execution of the command), I wanted to use the extensions mentioned in [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34458/reference-overlay-numbers-with-names#comment317649_50493) and [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34458/reference-overlay-numbers-with-names#comment317697_50493) in order to be able to define offsets.

When using the alternative `\savepause` definition, I get the error:

> ```
> "You can't use \`\unhbox' after \advance. \end{frame}"
> ```

When using the alternative `\usepauseoffset`, I get an error ...

> ```
> "undefined control sequence".
> ```

Actually, it's a whole bunch of errors in both cases. I'm not yet experienced enough with LaTeX to program macros and understand such error messages.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% Save overlays by name
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\savepause}[1]{\only<1>{\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\pauseentry{\the\c@framenumber}{#1}{\the\c@beamerpauses}}}}
%\DeclareRobustCommand*{\savepause}[2][0]{\only<1>{\advance\c‌​@beamerpauses by#1\relax\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\pauseentry{\the\c‌​@framenumber}{#2}{\t‌​he\c@beamerpauses}}\‌​advance\c@beamerpaus‌​es by-#1\relax}}
\newcommand*{\usepause}[1]{\@ifundefined{pauses@\the\c@framenumber @#1}{1}    {\@nameuse{pauses@\the\c@framenumber @#1}}}
\def\usepauseoffset[#1]#2{\number\numexpr\usepause{#2}+#1\re‌​lax}
\newcommand*{\pauseentry}[3]{\global\@namedef{pauses@#1@#2}{#3}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \visible<+->{Overlay 1 \savepause{first} (Counter: \usepause{first})}

    \visible<+->{Overlay 2 \savepause{second} (Counter: \usepause{second})}

    \visible<\usepause{first}->{Should be shown together with "Overlay 1".}

    %\visible<\usepauseoffset[1]{second}->{Should be shown together with "Overlay 2".} % Does not compile.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I'm sorry that I did not comment under the original question, but I do not yet have the privileges to comment.

In case anything is missing in my explanation, please let me know. I just joined Stackexchange.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Two different things need fixing.

First, there is some typo in `\relax` in the definition of `\usepauseoffset`.  The peculiar highlighting of the code is a hint of this.  Some invisible characters have got in between the `e` and the `l`.  Removing these lets your code compile with the last line uncommented.

More fundamentally, the new proposed version of the `\savepause` definition does indeed have problems.  Instead of stepping the counter, you can just save an adjusted value, e.g. by doing a `\numexpr` computation.

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\savepause}[2][0]{\only<1>{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\pauseentry
  {\the\c@framenumber}{#2}{\number\numexpr\c@beamerpauses-#1\relax}}}}
```

Putting this together gives a first slide with

[image: Sample output]

and the other slides behaving as requested.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\savepause}[2][0]{\only<1>{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\pauseentry
  {\the\c@framenumber}{#2}{\number\numexpr\c@beamerpauses-#1\relax}}}}

\newcommand*{\usepause}[1]{\@ifundefined{pauses@%
  \the\c@framenumber @#1}{1}{\@nameuse{pauses@\the\c@framenumber @#1}}}

\def\usepauseoffset[#1]#2{\number\numexpr\usepause{#2}+#1\relax}

\newcommand*{\pauseentry}[3]{\global\@namedef{pauses@#1@#2}{#3}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \visible<+->{Overlay 1 \savepause[1]{first} (Counter:~\usepause{first})}

    \visible<+->{Overlay 2 \savepause[1]{second} (Counter:~\usepause{second})}

    \visible<\usepause{first}->{Should be shown together with ``Overlay 1''.}

    \visible<\usepause{second}->{Should be shown together with ``Overlay 2''.}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \visible<+->{Overlay 1 \savepause[1]{first}
  (Counter:~\usepause{first})}

  \visible<+->{Overlay 2 \savepause[1]{second}
  (Counter:~\usepause{second})}

  \visible<\usepauseoffset[1]{first}->{Should be shown together with
  ``Overlay 2''.}

  \visible<\usepause{second}->{Should be shown together with ``Overlay
  2''.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```