# conflict between allowframebreaks and itemize[<+->] in beamer

Tags: beamer, itemize

Is there any substitute for itemize with [<-+>] option that has no conflict with beamer frame "allowframebreaks" option? using allowframebreaks will not allow [<-+>] option of itemize to do its work

Comment: the answer is simple: don't use `allowframebreaks`, it is evil!

Comment: Each \item creates a new page in the PDF.  How is beamer supposed to keep track or which pages are <> and which are real pages?

Comment: It seems that my question a bit ambiguous. I want to have two slides with the same title which has itemize. since the allowframebreaks break the itemize sequence job, I wanted something for substitution rather than doing it by hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `itemize` you don't have to worry about consecutive numbering, so you can simply use two `itemize` environments:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}

\begin{onlyenv}<1-6>
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item item 1
        \item item 2
        \item item 3
        \item item 4
        \item item 5
        \item item 6
    \end{itemize}
\end{onlyenv}

\begin{onlyenv}<7-12>
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item item 7
        \item item 8
        \item item 9
        \item item 10
        \item item 11
        \item item 12
    \end{itemize}
\end{onlyenv}

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any possibility to set a flag or bookmark for some object to set its presence after or before something else?

Comment: @V.Ajall I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I want to show an image with an specific item number.

Comment: @V.Ajall Sorry, but I do not understand what you are trying to do. Maybe ask a new question with some example what you are trying to do?

Comment: If you put <2>includegraphic{...} before \end{frame} 
it will be shown with second item in itemize. i want to set a flag for an item(not necessary to know its index number in itemize) and then show it with that specific item!

Comment: @V.Ajall Is https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50493/36296 what you are looking for?

Comment: absolutely yes!