# Combining <+-> with allowframebreaks in beamer

Tags: beamer, allowframebreaks

My question is closely related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396815/conflict-between-allowframebreaks-and-itemize-in-beamer), but slightly different, so that @samcarter's answer to that question doesn't help.

I want to combine the `allowframebreaks` option with the `<+->` option but using the standard way to combine options doesn't achieve this.   Here's an MWE.  The first frame uses `allowframebreaks` in the standard way, producing two pages.   The second frame tries to combine the two options, implements the `\pause` command but ignores the `allowframebreaks` option.     Reversing the order of the two options generates an error.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Title}
This is a test

\pause
This is a test

\newpage
Page 2
\pause

This is a test

\pause

This is a test
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[<+->,allowframebreaks]{Title}
This is a test

\pause
This is a test

\newpage
Page 2
\pause

This is a test

\pause

This is a test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you can't use the same technique as in the linked question.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[<+->]
\frametitle{Title}

    \begin{onlyenv}<-2>
        This is a test1

        \pause

        This is a test2
    \end{onlyenv}

    \begin{onlyenv}<.(2)->
        Page 2 3

        \pause
        \pause  

        This is a test 4

        \pause

        This is a test 5
    \end{onlyenv}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

To add a relevant quote from the beamer user guide:

> The use of this option is evil. In a (good) presentation you prepare each slide carefully and think twice before putting something on a certain slide rather than on some different slide. Using the allowframebreaks option invites the creation of horrible, endless presentations that resemble more a “paper projected on the wall” than a presentation. Nevertheless, the option does have its uses. Most noticeably, it can be convenient for automatically splitting bibliographies or long equations.