# Problem with onslide command while using beamer

Tags: beamer, overleaf, presentations

I am preparing a presentation using beamer and have encountered a problem. In my frame, no slides load after the first one when I use this code. I wish for my sentences to appear in different slides, but not as a list, hence  I tried to use onslide command, which didn't appear to work.

```
 \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Smooth Structure on Manifolds}
        \onslide<1->{We wish to introduce the notion of smoothness for manifolds. Let $M$ be an n-manifold, and $f:M\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a map.}
        \onslide<2->{One plausible criteria for smoothness of $f$ at a given point $p$ can be to check for smoothness of the local representative function of $f$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. if $(U,\varphi)$ is a chart containing $p$, then:}
        \onslide<3->{$$f:M\to \mathbb{R}^n\ \text{is smooth at}\ p \iff f\circ \varphi^{-1}:{\varphi(U)}\to \mathbb{R}^n \ \text{is smooth at}\ p$$}           
    \end{frame}
```

Please help with the issue, or recommend some other command for the task. I tried `\pause` but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: It works for me if I remove `[allowframebreaks]`. Do you need it?

Comment: It is also not suggested to use `[allowframebreaks]`. In fact, it causes problems with overlays. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/400090/133968

Comment: @Zxcvasdf Ah, not really. It works without `[allowframebreaks]`

Comment: @DevanshKamra Like the beamer user guide says: the allowframebreaks option is evil :)

Comment: Yes, I'll keep it in mind. It works now. Thanks!