# How to use \pause with allowframebreaks?

Tags: beamer

I need to use `allowframebreaks` to break my frame which cotains many items, added to it I added th `\pause` but it does not work with `allowframebreaks`:

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{title}
\begin{itemize}
 \item {
    text here
  }
 \begin{figure}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=3cm, height= 3cm]{images/image.png}
   \caption{}
   \label{}
 \end{figure}
 \item {
    \pause
    ext here
  }
 \framebreak
 \item {
      text here
  }
 \end{itemize}
 \end{frame}
```

How can I do combine `\pause` and `allowframebreaks`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: @Cragfelt I don't understand what's wrong with my question, however I tried to edit it.

Comment: related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396815/conflict-between-allowframebreaks-and-itemize-in-beamer and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400066/combining-with-allowframebreaks-in-beamer?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: To quote from the beamer manual ' You can use the option
allowframebreaks to cause the〈frame text〉to be split among
several slides, though you cannot use overlays then'.

Comment: `allowframebreaks` is evil!