# Describe overlays relatively to other overlays in beamer

Tags: beamer, overlays

I first thought [this amazing trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34458/reference-overlay-numbers-with-names) would do, but I can find no way of setting overlays *relatively* to one specific event: my dream:

```
% <:name:XXX> would mean "use overlay specification XXX and label
%             corresponding pause as `name`".
% <(name)XXX> would mean "use overlay specification XXX relatively 
%             to pause `name` and not to zero.
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item              first   \visible<(anchor1).(1)->{fourth}        % one after anchor1
    \item              second  \visible<(anchor2)->{fifth}             % exactly anchor2
    \item<:anchor1:+-> third   \visible<(anchor1)+->{fourth}           % one more after anchor1
    \item              fourth  \visible<(anchor1)+->{fifth}            % one more after anchor1
    \item<:anchor2:+-> fifth   \visible<(anchor2)+->{sixth}            % one more after anchor2
    \item              sixth   \visible<:anchor3:(anchor2)+->{seventh} % one more after anchor2, label this `anchor3`
    \item              seventh \visible<(anchor3)+->{eighth}           % one more after anchor3
\end{itemize}
```

Does this somehow already exists?
How hard would it be to implement?
How many times would it require the document to be compiled until stabilization?

Obviously, responsibility for non-looping specifications would be left to user.

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34458/reference-overlay-numbers-with-names could help

Comment: @samcarter Wops! This is the post I actually intended to refer two. Sorry for that, I'll edit mine :(