# Save slide numbers for further use in a document

Tags: beamer

I want that multiple things appear simultaneously on a same slide, but I don't want to calculate the number of this slide. I try to save it for futher reuse.

I want to do that several times.

For example, tikzpicture stuff simultaneously with a list.

Hre is my non working try.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\Slide}[1]{% 
\expandafter\newcommand\csname Sl#1\endcsname{\thebeamerpauses}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{enumerate}[<+->]

\item 
\item \Slide{A}
\item 

\end{enumerate}

\onslide<\SlA->{Appears on slide 2;}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: maybe have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34458/reference-overlay-numbers-with-names

Comment: Thanks. I knew this answer but I didn't remember it.

Comment: So close this one as duplicate?